# Opencv video capture not working in Dell laptop

Tags: opencv, webcam

I have made one executable whose main function is to display live video. I have tried this exe on other systems as well and it is working perfectly. the problem is that when i run this exe on dell laptop, there is no output of live image except the LED of the webcam is on. Whereas, when i connect external camera on the dell laptop, the exe correctly detects and shows the output live video. Any suggestions, why this is happening specifically with dell laptop?

Comment: Make sure the build-in camera is enabled in the BIOS of your Dell notebook and check the Windows camera privacy settings.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the issue is with video device ID. Most probably you have hard coded the device id as follows

```
VideoCapture cap(0);
```

where 0 is our webcam ID. Recompile your code with different ID like 1,2,... and check.

Comment: I have tried with other device id such as 1,2,3,4 and so on but the behaviour is the same i.e. led is turned on but no image display. The target system on which i want to run my exe has opencv3 installed. When i try to run videocapture cap(0) in opencv3, it runs perfectly. I was wondering whether opencv3 has binded the webcam with itself or something related to it?